# How to use text file to load file paths to excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, filepath

Ok, I have a macro in excel which is working perfectly.

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, folder As Scripting.folder, file As Scripting.file, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim directory As String

    directory = "O:\test\1"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(directory)


    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open directory & Application.PathSeparator & file.Name

        Set wb = Workbooks("Equipment Further Documentation List.xls")
    For Each sh In Workbooks("1.xls").Worksheets
        sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Next sh

     ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
     ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

        End If

    Next file
End Sub
```

I want to modify it so I could read in file path from a text file run the macro and change the file path to another one listed in the text file and so on. As soon as the text file reaches EOF, stop the macro.

How should I change the code to make it happen.

```
directory = "O:\test\1"
```

The file paths in the .txt file are separated by return.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt as you see fit but you should get the idea!

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject


Dim txtStream As textStream


Set txtStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\....\PathtoFiles.txt", ForReading)

Do Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = txtStream.ReadLine
    If strNextLine <> "" Then
        ' Do something?
    End If
Loop
txtStream.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

The full answer is :

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()

Const ForReading = 1
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject

Dim txtStream As TextStream

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, folder As Scripting.folder, file As Scripting.file, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim directory As String

Set txtStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GrzegoP\Desktop\Project\test\paths.txt", ForReading)

Do Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = txtStream.ReadLine
    If strNextLine <> "" Then

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(strNextLine)


    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open directory & Application.PathSeparator & file.Name

        Set wb = Workbooks("Equipment Further Documentation List.xls")
    For Each sh In Workbooks("1.xls").Worksheets
        sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Next sh

     ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
     ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

        End If
    End If

    Next file

    Loop
txtStream.Close
End Sub
```